# I want to Make a Regex to check at each line if <b>12^ this comes then i want to make the line bold and make the font size of 12 How to achieve this?

Tags: java, regex

I want to check at each line if 
 `<b>12^` 
this comes then I want to make the line bold and make the font size of 12 How to achieve this?
I am getting a string like this

`<b>12^ Bill No.:TD-708FD\r\n
            <b>12^ Steward: \r\n 
            Cashier:pablo .\r\n 
            Date:2018-08-09 16:19:25\r\n 
            Kots:1\r\n
            --------------------------------------\r\n
            <b>11^ Item Qty Amt \r\n`

how can I achieve this and get the number so that I can make the font size according to it 
can this be done using regex please help me as i don't know regex and how to use it.

right now I am doing this like this

```
String ss="header\r\n--------------------------------------\r\n<b>12^Type:Table\r\n<b>12^ Table Number: 3\r\n-------------------------------- ------\r\n";
    StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();


    String tokens[]=data.split("\r\n");
    for (String token : tokens) {

        if (token.contains("<b>12^")) {
           String s1=token.replace("<b>12^", "").trim();
           str.append(s1);
           str.append("\n");

        }else if (token.contains("<b>14^")){
            String s2=token.replace("<b>14^", "").trim();
            str.append(s2);
            str.append("\n");
        }else if (token.contains("<b>11^")){
            String s2=token.replace("<b>11^", "").trim();
            str.append(s2);
            str.append("\n");
        }else{
            str.append(token).trimToSize();
            str.append("\n");
        }
```

i wanted to know can i parse using regex and get the number after the

```
<b> number ^
```

so that i can make the font size of that number

Comment: A) not clear what you are asking for. For the regex? Or how to format text (if so: for which "target"? B) even when that would be clear: questions that only drop requirements aren't appreciated here. So: clarify your input, and add your own efforts to solve the problem and point specifically where you are stuck.

Comment: @GhostCat i have updated the question hope you can help me now

Comment: Thanks, that is quite better.

Comment: sorry for before I am new to StackOverflow @GhostCat  can you help me with this problem please

Comment: How do you intend to apply the font size? I.e. what should `<b>12^content` be translated into? Something like `<span style="font-size: 12pt">content</span>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
String ss = "header\r\n--------------------------------------\r\n<b>12^Type:Table\r\n<b>12^ Table Number: 3\r\n-------------------------------- ------\r\n";
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

String tokens[]=data.split("\r\n");
String regex = "\\<b>(\\d*)\\^";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (String token : tokens) {

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(token);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String s1 = token.replace(matcher.group(0), "").trim();
        String number = matcher.group(1); // This is the number you want.
        // Do what you need with the value...
        str.append(s1);
        str.append("\n");
    } else {
        str.append(token).trimToSize();
        str.append("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: works well but i have to remove that  String regex = "\\<b>(\\d*)\\^" from this to this   String regex = "<b>(\\d*)\\^"   then its working fine   but the loop doesnt work fine

Answer (score 1):

In java swing or OpenJFX for instance one can use HTML:

```
s = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">"
    + "html { font-family: Courier, Monospaced; }"
    + "h3 { font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt; }"
    + "</style></head><body>"
    + s.replaceAll((^----*?)\r\n", "<hr>\r\n";
    + s.replaceAll("<b>12\\^(.*?)\r\n", "<h3>$1</h3>\r\n";
    + s.replaceAll("\r\n([^<].*?)$", "<p>$1</p>\r\n")
    + "</body></html>";
```

Doing this line by line probably is more robust, solid.

Comment: I have the custom fonts that I wanna use can this be done with using only java  ? i have an android app in which i want to use that

Comment: Android can display html too, but for Android there might be nicer answers I am not aware of. Fonts should be no problem.